# How can we handle multiple request formats like JSON or text in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using AVRO schema in our application, and I observed that if I get the text format as a request in my Kafka topic and I have observed that my offset gets stuck, and for testing the correct JSON format also I am not able to consume my message from Kafka. Manually I have to change my offset then only I can access my next message.
Could you please suggest how can I handle any message either JSON or text so that my offset and Kafka topic work without any blocker?

Currently, I have manually increased the offset value in the topic as a workaround but I am searching solution so that my application or Kafka topic it self handle this situation and avoid any manual work.

Answer (score 0):

If your consumer uses Avro deserializer, then yes, it's "stuck" because text (which JSON is also text), is not Avro, therefore your code will throw a deserialization exception.

How you handle that is modifiable. Sounds like you're not seeking past those events and rather letting your consumer crash or retry those events over and over again...

Without using Confluent Server server-side schema validation, then there's no way Kafka can prevent non Avro data from reaching your topic, so at the very least, you'll need some try catch logic in your deserializer to handle bad consumer records

Or, if you need to correctly handle multiple types, then you can look into specs like CloudEvents, with fields `type` and `data` that can be parsed, then delegate to a more appropriate deserializer for any type.